# I need to write the right Assert in test method (java)/IntellijIdea

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertion

everyone! I have the task to simplify test code. After annotation @Test – the source code that must be simplified.  In the end it is my suggestion how to do that...
I need to test the method “testGetTransportMilitaryPlanes”. This method must return all military planes with “MilitaryType.TRANSPORT”. Actually I need to write one correct Assert without “for –if”  block (supposedly :)) and useless variables like “flag”.
Both versions of tests passed (The source and the corrected mine), but I think that I verify that method returns only one particular plane and the test won’t be correct if some new plane with the “MilitaryType.TRANSPORT” is added into the List. I feel something should be done with the “militaryPlane.getType()”  and “MilitaryType.TRANSPORT”. May be it is possible to wrap them correctly in one AssertEquals…???
Thanks’ in advance for help and your suggestions.

```
  public class AirportTest {
    private static List<Plane> planes = Arrays.asList(
            new PassengerPlane("Boeing-737", 900, 12000, 60500, 164),
            new PassengerPlane("Boeing-737-800", 940, 12300, 63870, 192),
            new PassengerPlane("Boeing-747", 980, 16100, 70500, 242),
            new PassengerPlane("Airbus A320", 930, 11800, 65500, 188),
            new PassengerPlane("Airbus A330", 990, 14800, 80500, 222),
            new PassengerPlane("Embraer 190", 870, 8100, 30800, 64),
            new PassengerPlane("Sukhoi Superjet 100", 870, 11500, 50500, 140),
            new PassengerPlane("Bombardier CS300", 920, 11000, 60700, 196),
            new MilitaryPlane("B-1B Lancer", 1050, 21000, 80000, MilitaryType.BOMBER),
            new MilitaryPlane("B-2 Spirit", 1030, 22000, 70000, MilitaryType.BOMBER),
            new MilitaryPlane("B-52 Stratofortress", 1000, 20000, 80000, MilitaryType.BOMBER),
            new MilitaryPlane("F-15", 1500, 12000, 10000, MilitaryType.FIGHTER),
            new MilitaryPlane("F-22", 1550, 13000, 11000, MilitaryType.FIGHTER),
            new MilitaryPlane("C-130 Hercules", 650, 5000, 110000, MilitaryType.TRANSPORT),
            new experimentalPlane("Bell X-14", 277, 482, 500, ExperimentalTypes.HIGH_ALTITUDE, ClassificationLevel.SECRET),
            new experimentalPlane("Ryan X-13 Vertijet", 560, 307, 500, ExperimentalTypes.VTOL, ClassificationLevel.TOP_SECRET)
    );

    private static PassengerPlane planeWithMaxPassengerCapacity = new PassengerPlane("Boeing-747", 980, 16100, 70500, 242);

    @Test
// Below is the test code to be simplified
  public void testGetTransportMilitaryPlanes() {
        Airport airport = new Airport(planes);
        List<MilitaryPlane> transportMilitaryPlanes = airport.getTransportMilitaryPlanes();
        boolean flag = false;
        for (MilitaryPlane militaryPlane : transportMilitaryPlanes) {
            if ((militaryPlane.getType() == MilitaryType.TRANSPORT)) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(flag, true);
    }

// My corrected version
public void testGetTransportMilitaryPlanes() {
Airport airport = new Airport(planes);
 List<MilitaryPlane> transportMilitaryPlanes = airport.getTransportMilitaryPlanes();
Assert.assertTrue(transportMilitaryPlanes.contains(new MilitaryPlane("C-130 Hercules", 650, 5000, 110000, TRANSPORT)));
    }
```

Comment: Can you add additional external libraries to your project? AssertJ covers your use case.

Comment: I will try to find out what is it. (I have never used it before)

Comment: You can find good tutorials here https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-assertj and https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html

Comment: Thanks' for sharing link.

Answer (score 0):

Your test code need a lot of configuration. Your test data contain lots of information not relevant for the test case. This is a problem since your test code is part of your codes *documentation* and should clearly state what is being tested and what the relevant properties of the test data are. In your case the object you expect to be found is an implementation of `MilitaryPlane` and returns a special value when its `getType` method is called.

You might consider using a *mocking framework* like `Mockito` to simplify your test code.

Then I'd rewrite your test like this:

```
public class AirportTest {
  private  List<Plane> civilPlanes = new ArrayList<>();

  @BeforeEach
  void setup(){
    for (i=0;i<10;){
       civilPlanes.add(Mockito.mock(Plane.class,"Civil Plane "+(++i)));      
    }
  }

  
    @Test
    public void testGetTransportMilitaryPlanes() {
        //arrange
        MilitaryPlane transporter = 
              Mokcito.mock(MilitaryPlane.class 
                          ,"Military Transporter");
        doReturn(MilitaryType.TRANSPORT).when(transporter).getType();
        List<Plane> allPlanes = new ArrayList<>(civilPlanes);
        allPlanes.add(transporter);
        Collections.shuffle(allPlanes);
        Airport airport = new Airport(allPlanes);
        //act
        List<MilitaryPlane> transportMilitaryPlanes = 
               airport.getTransportMilitaryPlanes();
        //assert (unsing assertj)
        assertThat(transportMilitaryPlanes)
           .as("select the only transporter")
           .contains(transporter);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks' for sharing your solution and spending time for reviewing my code. But actually It is not allowed for me (in frame of the task) to rewrite the whole code of the class AirportTest and use a mocking framework... (Supposedly I should mentioned about this in the beginning). I have to correct the code of the testGetTransportMilitaryPlanes() method without additional frameworks and mocking. As I feel, I need somehow to get the right access to the militaryPlane.getType() and pass it to the AssertEquals or AssertTrue methods...